# IOS CoreData, which NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType to use and why?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I can't make any sense out of the documentation for NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType. Which type would I use for the following situation, and why?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:???];
    [self loadRecordsFromCoreData];
}


- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {

[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    //[self.managedObjectContext reset]; //do I need to do this?
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"display == YES"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES]]];

    self.items = nil;
    self.items = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

}];

[self displayItems];
}
```

-displayItems will display views based on the properties of the objects in the self.items array, such as item.image, item.title, item.descriptionText, etc.

Comment: Are you going to be using it from multiple threads?

Comment: No. And should individual view controllers have their own context? Or should I just have one main context in the app delegate? I have 3 view controllers that create their own contexts like this.

Comment: The problem is that it is not thread safe.  If you plan to only call it from one thread, you can use the default type (thread confinement type).  You only need one per thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

UI events, such as view did load, take place on the main thread. You'll be manipulating your objects on the main thread (self.items in this case), so you should ensure that they are fetched into the context / saved on that thread as well.

`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` is for contexts whose work is to be done on a background thread.